# Hide Blank Columns in a Matrix Visualization or Show Measure Only for Total

Tags: powerbi

I am relatively new to Power BI and have been asked to make some enhancements to an existing report

The report is a listing of users with the corresponding number of assets in a particular status.  The enhancement I have been asked to make and having trouble with is adding a column that shows a calculated percentage.

I have attempted to create a custom measure, but when I do so, it adds the measure next to each column.  I only want the measure to display after the total and have not been able to figure out how to do this.

Below is a simplified version of the report, where the calculation is just (status2+ Status3)/Total

[image: Current Visualization]

Visualization with Measure
[image: My Attempt]

Desired Result

[image: Desired Result]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure there isn't an elegant way to do this at this time.

The only workarounds I can think of are terrible options involving creating multiple visuals, creating a measure per column, or hard coding column headers.

---

Here are some related ideas you can vote and comment on to add your support to encourage Microsoft to fix this limitation:

[Hide/Show Column on Table](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/30945430-hide-show-column-on-table)

[Show/Hide columns in report based on expression.](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/8758534-show-hide-columns-in-report-based-on-expression)

[Power BI hide/show column](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/20211892-power-bi-hide-show-column)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something, this can be handled in PowerBI without building any measures.

I assume you are starting with a data table like this:

```
User    Status1 Status2 Status3
User1   2       3       4
User2   1       2       1
User3   2       3       1
```

Then use the Power Query Editor to add columns
[image]

I created a Total columns with the formula:

```
 = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Addition", each [Status1] + [Status2] + [Status3], Int64.Type)'
```

Then a column for Status2 + Status3:

```
 = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Addition", each [Status2] + [Status3], Int64.Type)
```

Then the Calculation:

```
 = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Addition1", "Division", each [Addition] / [Total], type number)
```

With some renaming of columns, the result:

```
User    Status1 Status2 Status3 Total   Status2+Status3 Calculation
User1   2       3       4       9       7               0.777777778
User2   1       2       1       4       3               0.75
User3   2       3       1       6       4               0.666666667
```

Finally, a simple table visualization:

[image]